# Salvar IEnumerable<T> dentro de uma entidade pai com LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, collection, linq-to-entities

Prezados tenho as seguintes classes:

```
   public class Foto
   {
      [Key]
      public int Id { get; set; }

      [StringLength(500)]
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Obrigatório")]
      public string Nome { get; set; }

      public int Item_Id { get; set; }
      [ForeignKey("Item_Id")]
      public virtual IEnumerable<Item> Item { get; set; 
   }


  public class Item
  {
     [Key]
     public int Id { get; set; }

     [StringLength(500)]
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Obrigatório")]
     public string Nome { get; set; }
  }
```

Preciso salvar na tabela item e na tabela fotos. É possível fazer isso dentro do mesmo _DbContext?

Tentei da maneira abaixo e não funcionou.

```
  _DbContext.Item.Add(new Entidade.Item
  {
     Id = item.Id,
     Nome = item.Nome,
     fotos = item.Fotos
   });

 _DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Alguma dica?

Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é possível, primeiro você insere uma entidade `Item` e logo em seguida uma entidade `Foto`, cada uma em seu `DbSet` correspondente dentro do `_DbContext`.

Exemplo:

```
var item1 = new Item { Nome = "Item 1" });
_DbContext.Item.Add(item1);
_DbContext.SaveChanges(); // Você precisa aplicar as mudanças aqui, para que
                          // o Item.Id seja preenchido pelo EF e possa ser
                          // utilizado na inserção abaixo como chave estrangeira
                          // Note que estou considerando que Item.Id seja
                          // uma Identity Column com auto incremento e que
                          // você esteja utilizando SQL Server, para que
                          // esse conceito seja válido

var foto1 = new Foto { Nome = "Foto 1", Item_Id = item1.Id };
_DbContext.Foto.Add(foto1);
_DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Funcionou!!! Muito obrigado Zignd. :)

Comment: Além de marcar como aceito, prestigie a resposta também com voto positivo. ;) @ThiagoRodolfo